# Android firebase запрос координат

Tags: android, firebase-android

Можно ли используя Firebase выводить GPS координаты пользователей (с их разрешения, конечно) с достаточно частым обновлением: раз в 5 сек, в определенном радиусе: 2-10 км, в количестве 30-40 пользователей, сколько запросов может обработать Firebase сервер в секунду?
Как передавать данные с аккаунта одного пользователя Firebase на другой, те же координаты, например?

Answer (score 2):

Можно с клиента получать координаты пользователей, и слать запросы на сервер так часто, как ты хочешь, если ты готов платить за нагрузку на сервер. А как передавать данные координат с одного аккаунта на другой, я думаю тут одним firebase не обойтись, потому что firebase не дает возможности писать свою серверную часть. Вы можете использовать google app engine, на него слать координаты и id пользователей, он будет принимать ваш http запрос и на основании его слать запрос на firebase, а уже с firebase базы данных ваш клиент, как и обычно, будет получать данные.

Comment: У гугла есть даже туториалы с использованием firebase + server -> client.

Comment: Возможно вопрос немного не по теме, но может где нибудь видели как просто запиливать координаты(fixed) в firebase?).